# Make a loop run only once when script is added to gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that runs in editor as well as in Play Mode. However I want a loop to be executed ONLY ONCE when I add the script to a gameObject. That is I do not want it to be called 2nd time when I play the game. How is this possible?

```
[ExecuteAlways]
..
..
void Start()
{
for (int i = 0; i < Go.Count; i++) {
                //Only Once
}
}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the void Start() method of Unity

Comment: A bool check should do it. Just define a bool like isLoopExecuted and set it to false. Then put your loop in an if statement that checks if the bool is false. Set your bool to true inside your if statement.

Comment: @salyangoz yes ofc if I do it in play mode. But can I make the bool as static and make it false during edit mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `OnValidate` method who is called everytime your `MonoBehaviour` changed on editor time. You'll have to set a variable to validate that the script did the call.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    [SerializeField]
    private bool isInitializedOnEditor = false;




#if UNITY_EDITOR

    private void MySpecialMethod()
    {
        //...
    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if(isInitializedOnEditor == false)
        {
            MySpecialMethod();
            isInitializedOnEditor = true;
            //Don't forget to save your change on this gameobject if require
            UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

I used attributes `[HideInInspector]` and `[SerializeField]` to set the bool serializable (because otherwise the next time you load the scene it'll call the method again) but not show on inspector (you don't want the unity editor user can change it manually).

`#if UNITY_EDITOR` is required otherwise you cant compile because `UnityEditor` is only available on editor mode.

`SetDirty()` is used to tell Unity this `MonoBehaviour` have change and it should serialize it again. Otherwise the next time you will load the scene you'll loose your change here. You don't have to use it if your code job don't change the `MonoBehaviour`

**Edit**

If you don't want to call you method when on play mode, you can make it like:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        if (isInitializedOnEditor == false && Application.isPlaying == false)
        {
            MySpecialMethod();
            isInitializedOnEditor = true;
            //Don't forget to save your change on this gameobject if require
            UnityEditor.EditorUtility.SetDirty(this);
        }
    }
#endif
```

**Note on `== false`**

When I need to use a if and check if a bool is false I prefer to write the whole comparison `if(myBool == false)` than the shortcut `if(!myBool)` for readability purpose. We could debate it but it's on purpose.

Comment: Is it possible that I can run in loop only during edit mode and never during Play mode?

Comment: If you don't want to validate on editor when play mode. Just add `Application.isPlaying == false` as condition.

Comment: If all that is supposed to only run in the editor then you could move the entire method between the `#if UNITY_EDITOR` pre-processors as well actually.

Comment: @derHugo Yes. At first I thought he/she wanted to do it once in editor and once on start. I'll update.
PS : I rollback your edit about `== false` change and I explained why on my post. If you didn't agree with me you can change it again.

Comment: @D.B a matter of taste and its fine. I just know many people (including myself lol) who prefer using the short variant `if(someThing)` and `if(!someThing)`. Reason: It is way shorter to write stuff this way and well known so actually the readability isn't lost here ;) But as said .. probably just a matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

Use break;

```
[ExecuteAlways]
..
..
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Go.Count; i++) {
                //Only Once
    break;
    }
}
```

The Loop will run Once till it hits the break, and the the loop will end.